# Calculate value needed to reach target by the end of a year

Tags: c#, sql

I have a set of values (scores to a particular KPI), these are reported monthly. I need to calculate what I'd have to score every month from now until the end of the year to reach that target.

I'm more interested in the algorithm/maths involved in the calculation than a programming solution at the moment.

I've provided some example data here.

[Example Data](http://1drv.ms/1gHcbid)

[image: Picture of data]

In this example I have manually guesstimated that 9.1316 for the final six months of the year will allow the score to climb to the target by the end of the year.

What I'd like to understand is how to calculate that from the current YTD value, the target and the number of months remaining.

Depending on the way the solution worked, I'd either implement it straight in SQL, or it would be in the code of the program itself (C#)

Comment: If you can add formula in excel, you definately can make algo of it.

Comment: Is `YTD` the average so far?  You may find it easier to look at the total instead.

Comment: Hi Teepeemm. Yes, YTD is the average of the previous months leading up to now.